# Create ListView with popup window?

Tags: android, listview

Is there a way to create ListView with custom adapter to do next:
When item 1 is pressed, to push down other listview items and inflate some view?
Something like this:
[image: This is normal ListView, not p ressed]

[image: This is listview with pressed item.]

What is the right way to do this? What should I use? I tried with expandable listview but I can't make the buttons to be horizontal.

Comment: To do this you have to show the view over your custom view on view click inside adapter.

Comment: Exactlly, and I think that you just gave me an idea. Going to try with hiding buttons view.gone and showing them on click.

Comment: Yeah, right, just try once.

Comment: can't you implement the ExpandableListView and when the list item is expanded you show a custom layout with a horizontal Linear layout
(I guess this will only work if you have a finite amount of buttons you want to show, not dynamic)

Comment: Yeah, if you know the fixed items to display then you can do this.

Comment: Yeah that seems like a good idea but setting items on View.GONE/View.Visible works too. What should I do now lol
@SurenderKumar didn't really gave me answer but thanks to him I got the idea how to do it.

Comment: Try both one by one and choose that suits you. ;P

Comment: Nah not gonna bother with it anymore, I got what I wanted, I am just going to add some animations. It's even better because code is much shorter, easier to work with. If you could write an answer or just copy/paste what u wrote up there so i can accept it as Answer?

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

here is the [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Use linear layout (horizontal) in the child view for equispaced horizontal buttons in the expanded view.